# when adding a relationship object w/ core data get "property cannot be found in forward class object" error

Tags: objective-c, core-data, entity, relationship

I have a core data model with four entities. The entity `Player` has a to-Many relationship to the other entities (`Player_Scores,Custom_Exercise,Selected_Exercise`).

In my app delegate, I make `NSManagedObjectContext,NSManagedObjectModel,NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` properties in the standard way. Then, in a different view controller, I declare ivars for an `NSManagedObjectContext` object and a `newPlayer` Player entity in the **@interface:**

```
@interface NewProfileViewController()
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
    Player *newPlayer;
}
```

Then in an action I have the following code to create a Player entity and enter in its attributes, as well as a `Player_Scores` entity and a `Selected_Exercise` entity. The code i use successfully adds the attributes for the `Player_Scores` and the Player entities. However when I try to add 16 `Selected_Exercise` entities in a loop and set their attributes I get a big fat "*Property cannot be found on forward class object?*" error. HELP!!!!! Like i said the code is the same for `Selected_Exercise` and for `Player_Scores`. I already tried re-starting, deleting database, etc. It's a compiler error that pops up when i try to do `newEx.exercise=@"blahblahblah";` or `newEx.suit=@"blahblahblah";` UGH

Below is my code for that method:

```
     //1. save a person to database
        newPlayer=[NSEntityDescription
                           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player"
                           inManagedObjectContext:context];

        newPlayer.name=newentry;
        //NSError *error; [context save:&error];

        //2. begin making a score card:
        Player_Scores *newScoreCard = [NSEntityDescription
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player_Scores"
                               inManagedObjectContext:context];

        newScoreCard.date_of_game = [NSDate date];
        newScoreCard.player=newPlayer; //attach this score card to the new playe
        [newPlayer addScoresObject:newScoreCard];//add the score card to the newplayer
        //3.  make selected_exercise

        NSString *plistCatPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ListOfExercises" ofType:@"plist"]; //grab plist
        NSMutableArray* theDictArray= [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistCatPath] copy];

        for(int cnt=0;cnt<[theDictArray count];cnt++){

            Selected_Exercise *newEx= [NSEntityDescription
                                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Selected_Exercise"
                                       inManagedObjectContext:context];
            newEx.exercise=[[theDictArray objectAtIndex:cnt]valueForKey:@"exercise"];
            newEx.suit=[[theDictArray objectAtIndex:cnt]valueForKey:@"suit"];
            [newPlayer addSelected_exerciseObject:newEx];
            NSLog(@"added exercise %@ for suit %@ at array index %d",[[theDictArray objectAtIndex:cnt]valueForKey:@"exercise"],[[theDictArray objectAtIndex:cnt]valueForKey:@"suit"],cnt);
        }
    // Save everything
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"The save was successful!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"The save wasn't successful: %@", [error userInfo]);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds as if you imported "Player.h", but not "Selected_Exercise.h" in that file.

"Player.h" probably contains the forward declaration `@class Selected_Exercise`, so that
the compiler does not complain on

```
Selected_Exercise *newEx = [NSEntityDescription ...
```

But if "Selected_Exercise.h" is not imported, the properties of that class, such as 
`newEx.exercise`, are unknown to the compiler.

Comment: That was it! To my utter embarrassment I took a look at the top of my viewcontroller's .m file to find that I didn't declare Selected_Exercise.h :-/ there goes three hours.